# Queries in multiple loop and Ordering by id of last query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have two `while` loops and two queries in the loops.

I must order `posts` as DESC by its IDs. But posts loop is under another query's loop.

```
$follows=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM follows WHERE follower=:login");
$follows->execute([':login'=>$login['id']]);
while($followed=$follows->fetch()) {

    $posts=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE user=:followed ORDER BY id DESC");
    $posts->execute([':followed'=>$followed['following']]);
    while($post=$posts->fetch()) {

    ?>

    ...

    <?php }} ?>
```

This method is ordering posts depending on ID numbers of the follows table.
I want to order posts as DESC for only IDs of posts. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you might be overcomplicating this. If you want a single dataset, then you should use a single, joined query. You can execute it once, and then loop over the results with php:

```
select ...
from follows f
inner join posts p on p.user = f.following
where f.follower = :login
order by p.id desc
```

Note that I left the `select` clause empty. You should really enumerate the columns that you want (and, if needed, alias them to avoid conflicts) rather than use `*`: this way, the structure of the resultset is explicit .